# html/javascript next and back buttons

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to code a div with next/back buttons that change the content shown in the div when they're clicked. i could do this by just having it go to a different page entirely, but that would require me to make a lot of pages and i don't want to do that. this likely has an extremely easy solution but unfortunately i am not very smart when it comes to javascript . i've tried looking online for tutorials but none of them are showing me what i'm trying to achieve.

i have very basic code for this here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="changediv">click the button</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">the button</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("changediv").innerHTML = "one";
  document.getElementById("changediv").innerHTML = "two";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

what's supposed to happen is when the button is clicked it shows "one", and then when the button is clicked while it's showing "one" it goes to "two" and so on so forth. instead it just skips straight to two.

Comment: the code in that function does what you told it to do - how is the code supposed to know you want to stop at "one"?

Comment: Are the next/back moving through a list and wrapping around at the ends, or "browser history"-like, or something else? Is the value just going to increase by one on each click, or can it decrease too, or even be set to specified number? Please edit your question to include this info, and preferably a runnable example.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is probably more along the lines of what you're looking for. Where you have an array of strings, and you increment through the array with every click.

```js
<script>
const buttonTitles = ["one", "two"]
let index = 0
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("changediv").innerHTML = buttonTitles[index++];
}
</script>
```

Not sure what you intend to happen once you click more than twice, but there are many options.  I've left it open for you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you're overwriting the content immediately with "two" after setting it to "one." To achieve the desired effect, you can use a variable to keep track of the current state and then update the content accordingly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="changediv">click the button</div>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">the button</button>
  <script>
    var state = 1;
    function myFunction() {
      var div = document.getElementById("changediv");
      if (state === 1) {
        div.innerHTML = "one";
        state = 2;
      } else if (state === 2) {
        div.innerHTML = "two";
        state = 1; 
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```